# Spring Boot Rest Multilanguage

Tags: spring-boot, internationalization, microservices

I have an application, that uses Angular 2 for UI and Spring Boot Rest as a microservice. As a database, I have PostgreSQL.
I want this project to support multi-languages.
I heard that spring has something called i18n, but I don't know how to implement it.

One of my microservice is called categories, and what it does is CRUD operations. The default language is English, but I want to add french. So, if a call is like this: 
get: http://localhost:8080/categories?lang=fr
I will get all the categories, where lang = 'fr'

Also, probably I will add a table called `static_texts`, where I will add words to translate, like: `contact`, `menu`, `testimonials`, etc. And for these words, when a user entered for the first time on site, angular will make a call to java to get all the static words, to save in a session, and to add those into the template.

Like this I see the multilanguage system, but, I don't understand how to implement it into my project. Do you have an example, because I couldn't find anything for what I need?
Thanks!

Comment: I18n works with messages files you need to create messages_fr.properties for French anyway here is basic usage tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization and here is how to do it with database table https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7

Comment: @bogdan Did the answer resolve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot can manage any number of locales in an application flawlessly. Internationalization is a great way to increase users on a product so there are no limits in terms of how users use your product.

1. The first and simple solution is to implement a **LocaleResolver** and  **LocaleChangeInterceptor** for managing some resource files for different languages. you can see [this tutorial](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/spring-boot-internationalization/).
   However, this approach depends on the access to the application’s resource files when adding a new supported language or modify the existing message files. In case an end-user is responsible for this job and obviously, this is not an optimal approach.
2. Hence, the second method shows how to move all of our localized messages to a database. This enables the end-user to add a new language or update existing localized messages at runtime with the help of [**i18n**](https://www.i18next.com/). In [this tutorial](https://medium.com/i18n-and-l10n-resources-for-developers/database-stored-messages-for-i18n-in-spring-boot-11dc2ee5c1f7) you'll see how to use your table for translated texts